# Is there a way to redirect a request from API server to a different service in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, ingress-controller

I have read about ingress/ingress controller etc. But what I really want is to redirect request to API server to a new service. Some sort of webhook implementation. Say I have to request a resource creation, can that go through some custom validation and then proceed with creation.

Comment: While Stack Overflow does permit certain questions about Kubernetes, we require that they (like all questions asked here) be specifically related to programming. This question does not appear to be specifically related to programming, which makes it off-topic here. You might be able to ask questions like this one on [sf] or [DevOps](https://devops.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: A [validating webhook](https://developers.redhat.com/articles/2021/09/17/kubernetes-admission-control-validating-webhooks) can perform custom validation on arbitrary resources types. Is that what you're looking for?